# Unable to install fb watchman {command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1}

Tags: software-installation, python

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/****/watchman'
cd python && /usr/bin/python ./setup.py clean build_py -c -d . build_ext -i
running clean
removing 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7' (and everything under it)
error removing build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywatchman'
error removing build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7'
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pywatchman.bser' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pywatchman/bser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywatchman/bser.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywatchman/bser.o: Permission denied
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:2671: recipe for target 'py-build' failed
make[1]: *** [py-build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/***/watchman'
Makefile:722: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like a simple permission issue (did you unpack the source archive using `sudo` by any chance?)

Comment: Hi thanks,  I didn't need to, I just cloned the repository

Comment: Well, check the ownership and permissions e.g. `ls -al build`

Answer (score -1):

Disable python bindings, read [facebookgithub.io/watchman/install-from-source](http://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-from-source)

```
...
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-python
make
sudo make install
```